# Uploading a very large JSON file via REST using Java

Tags: java, rest

I have a very large json file (about 500MB) that I am trying to upload using REST and java. It works using curl like this -

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" --data-binary @2018-02-28.json http://md01:8086/Gateway/rest/gateway-service/ABC/invocations
```

However, I get "Software caused connection abort: socket write error" when I do it using REST like this-

```
String filePath = "C:\\2018-02-28.json";
String filename = "2018-02-28.json";
File uploadedFile = new File("C:\\2018-02-28.json");
try {
   // HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    String authHeader = authToken();
    HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder
            .create()
            .addTextBody("name", "fileDate")
            .addTextBody("fileName", filename)
            .addTextBody("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addBinaryBody("fileData", new File(filePath), ContentType.create("application/json"), filename)
            .build();

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionTimeToLive(2700, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setMaxConnTotal(400).setMaxConnPerRoute(400)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(30000).setConnectTimeout(5000).build())
            .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(5, true))
            .build();

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://md:8086/InputGateway/rest/input-gateway-service/ABC/invocations");
    request.setEntity(entity);
    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
    HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity1 = resp.getEntity();
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity1, "utf-8"));
    System.out.println("File has been Uploaded successfully: " + uploadedFile);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new Exception( ex.toString());
}
}
```

what am I doing wrong here

Comment: What library are you using? Have you tried Java's built-in `HttpClient`?

Comment: Some servers may implement traffic/size limits to prevent DOS issues. Contact the server owner for infos.

Comment: @Konrad if it works with curl it's not a server side issue

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" --data-binary @2018-02-28.json http://md01:8086/Gateway/rest/gateway-service/ABC/invocations
```

One thing you may want to do is run this command in verbose mode, to see what is really happening.  It is possible that the example that works because curl is using an [Expect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) header that allows the server to prepare for the data dump.

A packet analyzer, to see if the remote server is actually sending you a RST, or if something else is going on in the network stack.

(Obvious, but just in case: try using the same code to send a smaller file.  Make sure that the size it the limiting factor.  Doing a binary search to find out how big a file is acceptable might provide an extra clue.)